# How can I have a UIView slide out from under a UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewanimation

Currently I am displaying a UIView that slides down from the top of my window to a position:

```
-(void)showNotificationBar
{
    [notificationBar setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:notificationBar];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         [notificationBar setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 59, 320, 32)];
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];
}
```

I want this to slide out from under my UINavigationBar. Right now it is sliding from the top of the window, to the bottom of my navigation bar. I want it to slide from the bottom of the navigation bar to display itself. Now exactly sure how to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are having?

Comment: is the title of your navigation bar ever going to change? Im just trying to think of ideas to get this done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're adding `notificationBar` on top of all other views in your window.  You need to add it as a subview of the nav bar's superview, below the nav bar.

Let's say your `UINavigationBar` is in a property `self.navBar`.  Try this:

```
- (void)showNotificationBar
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.navBar.frame) - frame.size.height;
    notificationBar.frame = frame;

    [self.navBar.superview insertSubview:notificationBar belowSubview:self.navBar];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = notificationBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.navBar.frame);
        notificationBar.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```

Comment: On translucent navigationBar, does not work correctly.

Comment: This works well however when using a `UISearchDisplayController` the `navigationBar.superview` is nil. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at this and it looks like you want to research how to "Mask" a layer. 
Take a look at this post.

["Masking" an animation? iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763620/masking-an-animation-iphone-sdk)

If you were to mask your drop down menu under a view (a hidden view) you could get the animation to show without looking like it came from above your navigation bar, but below it.