# Animated Loading Screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I'd like to have a splash screen with some image animation.

The image is of the letter 'N' which needs to be filled with a single color in a fashion that makes each line (out of the 3) fill on its turn.

Is there a more elegant way than using `UIImageAnimation`?

EDIT:
Take this image for example: http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/64282/64282,1224026572,14/stock-photo-christmas-green-snowflake-capital-letter-n-18910459.jpg

Think of that green filling as what needs to be animatedly filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `CAShapeLayer` to animate the drawing of text.  I could give you an example, but to be honest Ole Begemann has an awesome example:

http://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/

Comment: This is excellent, but I didn't mean literally text of the letter 'N'.
I'm dealing with an image of the letter N. (with effects etc.)

Comment: Ah, I see.  In that case, you could just use a layer as a "mask", and animate that layer's position to create the fill effect.  See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1765090/456851